# how to obtain return address of current user stack frame from linux kernel x86_64 [VMI]

Tags: linux-kernel, x86-64

I want to obtain the return address of the current user stack frame
from some Linux kernel structure on a Linux x86_64 VM using a VMI-based approach. 
I can access the content of more or less all registers, but solely at the moment
of a context switch (CR3 event), so registers like RBP or RSP are
pointing to the kernel stack and not user stack.

My first approach was to obtain the stack/base pointer and derive
from it the offset to the return address. However, accessing the
task_struct member thread (type thread_struct) and inside of it the
members sp or usersp doesn't yield the desired result. The member
usersp does point to some area in the user stack, but it definitively does not
hold the current position of the user stack pointer. I used some simple
C program, which prints out the stack pointer within each function, to verify
the validity of the usersp member.

Another approach was to follow the ret_stack pointer (type ftrace_ret_stack) of task_struct that contains the member ret. This member refers to the same value
as the usersp member from above.

I could however derive the top of stack by accessing the field start_stack
from the structure mm_struct that is nested in the task_struct (a pointer to it). This information seems to come most closely to the actual stack pointer. But, I have no idea how to derive from it the desired return address.

I have noticed there is some raw pointer called stack within the task_struct,
but couldn't figure out any detailed information about it.

I'm aware of the 'trapframe' structure on Windows systems, but couldn't find
the equivalent on Linux.

Thanks in advance.